# A question of residue involved analytic branch

Tags: complex-analysis

Look at the following gragh,$$\int_{c}\frac{1}{z^{0.5}}\:dz=\int_{c}\frac{z^{0.5}}{z}\:dz$$where c denotes unit circle,then the residue of the integral at z=0 is $$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{z^{0.5}}{z}\right)=(z^{0.5})_{z=0}=0$$,as a consequence,the integral=0,but obviously,the integral is not equal to zero,where is  wrong about above approach.Here is another relevant question ,consider the residue of following integral at x=2 $$\int_{-1}^1\frac1{(x-2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}\:dx$$,First,we define complex function,that is $\frac1{(z-2)\sqrt{1-z^2}}$,then choose proper contour which contains only one simple poles,namely 2, after several steps,we are only left to calculate the residue at z=2 to solve the required integral, the answer choose a analytic branch -π to calculate the residue ,namely $\lim_{z\to2}\frac1{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ whose value is $\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$,I'm confused why not choose the branch π so that the result is $-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$.Can someone help me ,thank you

Comment: $z^{-1/2}$ does not have a simple pole. It's a branch point. No residue exists. Also, I have no idea what your second part is asking. Please rephrase the question and add more context.

Comment: @Dylan,I'm still confused about what your first part said,why no residue exists,the integrand is $\frac{z^{0.5}}{z}$,then using Cauchy’s integral formulas the integral is equal to $(z^{0.5})_{z=0}*2πi$

Comment: 1) $z^{1/2}$ is not holomorphic on any disk centered at $z=0$, 2) There is a branch cut on the negative real line, so any contour intersecting it (i.e. the unit circle) is not a closed loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define a contour as a disk with radius $R$

$C: z = Re^{it}, \quad -\pi < t < \pi$

where the two endpoints are placed just above and below the branch cut of $f(z) = z^{-1/2}$

Using the standard method, we can compute the integral along the contour as

\begin{align} 
\int_{C} f(z)\ dz &= \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(z(t))z'(t) dt \\ 
&= \int_{-\pi}^\pi R^{-1/2}e^{-it/2}iRe^{it}dt \\
&= i\sqrt{R} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{it/2} dt \\
&= i\sqrt{R} \left[\frac{2}{i}e^{it/2}\right]_{-\pi}^\pi \\
&= 4i\sqrt{R}
\end{align}

As you can see, this is dependent on $R$.

As for why there is no residue, remember that $z=0$ is not an isolated singularity of the function $z^{-1/2}$; it is in fact a branch point. It's not possible to define a closed contour enclosing it, since the function is discontinous on any arbitrarily small disk centered at the this point.